# Using Where on a page property

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

My blogposts has the property `WrittenDate` (`writtendate`) `DatePicker` type. How could I use Where to filter the list to only contain blogpost where `WrittenDate` is set (not `null`?)

I've tried

```
var posts = CurrentPage.Children.Where(p => p.writtendate != null)
```

but this does not work and crashes the site :) How can I fetch a property and check if it is set (`DatePicker` in this example)?

Answer (score 0):

The Umbraco `DatePicker` type  returns a `DateTime`, which is not nullable.

Empty fields will return `DateTime.MinValue`, so to return content with the `WrittenDate` property set:

```
var posts = CurrentPage.Children.Where("writtendate != @0", DateTime.MinValue);
```

Note, that with a dynamic node, the razor parser doesn't allow you to use lambda syntax to filter objects.